# How to built client android app to scan fingerprint form morpho scanner device

Tags: android, biometrics

I am new to Android, I have to build a biometric fingerprint scanner using morpho fingerprint device which scans and authenticate the user's and allow to do some operation in my app.

If there any way to do that then please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

For integrating Morpho Scanner Device in your android application visit below link from where you will get SDK for that device and instructions.

[MorphoKit SDK](https://www.morpho.com/en/morphokit-1)

You have to integrate above SDK in your application which will help you to integrate MorphoKit SDK.

Comment: How can i get MorphoKit SDK .In the given link it only given the description.

Comment: For that, you have to contact the local Morpho supplier for more information.